# How to show the entire List without scrolling in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way to make a List be of height that matches its content automatically?

I have a list that will show a number of items (I don't know in advance how many). By default, when I create the list, it doesn't get enough height, instead it shows 1-3 items and scrolls to show more. I would like to disable the scrolling behaviour.

I tried to hardcode frame height to some large value that I'm certain will fit all the items, but this isn't ideal. I can also calculate the frame height from itemHeight * numItems (if I set all the items to specified height themselves), but in my case the items can have varying heights.

Maybe there's a simpler solution for that?

I looked in the documentation, tried also .fixedSize(), different list styles etc. Those didn't work for me.

Comment: By saying list you mean a table view, right? If yes did you try `tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height` don't forget to `layoutIfNeeded()` after that.

Comment: By List, I mean SwiftUI List() https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list

Comment: is groupListStyle what you want?

Comment: @E.Coms I tried that, but it still keeps scrolling. I already have a ScrollView on that screen and I'm looking for a way to have the list to take as much height as it needs to show all items without scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `VStack` instead of a `List`. This will get rid of the scrolling behavior, but will still give vertically organized cells. You can still use `ForEach` inside if that's what you are doing inside `List`.

Comment: That's actually perfect! As a note, I wanted to have a separator like in a List, so I just wrapped the item in a VStack and added a Rectangle at the bottom. And this worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: A Divider is quite similar to to a separator. You might want to have a look at that as well.